# How to use Vlookup and HLookUP to set a range for CountIF

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I searched through the internet and StackOverflow but I did not find the exact relevant issue being resolved.

So I am trying to resolve the following issue.

I have a table with regions and some data in it.

I wanted to count how many Yes and No I have in the table for each region.

[Example Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPjkZ.png)
[image]

My Formula looks like this so far but does not work;

```
=COUNTIF(VLOOKUP("UK",A2:G9,3,TRUE,C2:G9),"Y")
```

So, I should receive 1 as an answer because there is only one "Y" for UK in DATA 1 column.

Comment: Your formula is malformed with misplaced brackets. While the general idea of what you want to accomplish is vaguely there, this question would benefit from sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) across all columns and determine the column for **Data 1** with the [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca).

```
=COUNTIF(A2:A9, "UK", INDEX(A2:G9, 0, MATCH("data 1", 1:1, 0)), "Y")
```

Alternately, use the following and fill down.

```
=COUNTIF(A$2:A$9, "UK", INDEX(A$2:G$9, 0, MATCH("data " & ROW(1:1), $1:$1, 0)), "Y")
```

Comment: Hi, both don't work. I am getting a formula error because COUNTIF has 2 arguments only and not 3.

Answer (score 0):

To count the number of Y or N for a single region, you can use Excel's [COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842).

For example, if you want to find how many times "Y" appears in DATA 1 for the "UK" Region, you would use
`=COUNTIFS(A2:A9,"UK",C2:C9,"Y")`